# Matching row values with column values in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, pivot-table, data-manipulation

```
  Holding Period      Classification Type                        Optimization & Gap Risk                                   Directional Risk
0     Short Term  Optimization & Gap Risk                      Frequency of Optimization                                   Beta Calibration
1    Medium Term         Directional Risk        Frequency of Data Input for alpha model                frequency of Beta or $ Rebalanciing
2      Long Term            Concentration  Ability to React to Change in Market Risk/Vol  Is beta/$ neutrality controlled through index,...
```

I want to match the values in the classification type column with the values of the following columns.

I want some type of list of all the values as the result.

```
  Holding Period      Classification Type     List
0     Short Term  Optimization & Gap Risk     ['Frequency of Optimization', 'Frequency of Data Input for alpha model', 'Ability to React to Change in Market Risk/Vol']
1    Medium Term         Directional Risk     ['Beta Calibration', 'frequency of Beta or $ Rebalanciing', 'Is beta/$ neutrality controlled through index, options or single name positions?']
2      Long Term            Concentration     NA
```

I hope this illustrates what I want. Basically an aggregation of all the value in the columns that have the same names as the values in the Classification Type column.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: you can't help yourself with data-frame I've given?

Comment: Optimization & Gap Risk, Directional Risk are values in the column "Classification Type" than they are column names.

Comment: You might use indexing, `cols = list(df['Classification Type'].values)`, then `df[cols]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

I would create a dictionary for the two columns by capturing all the values in the column as a list.

- Optimization & Gap Risk
- Directional Risk

You can do that as follows:

```
riskdict = {}
for col in df.columns[2:]:
    riskdict[col] = df[col].tolist()
```

Then I will map the `Classification Type` column to the dictionary. That will give you what you want.

The full code is:

```
riskdict = {}
for col in df.columns[2:]:
    riskdict[col] = df[col].tolist()

df['List'] = df['Classification Type'].map(riskdict)
print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

```
  Holding Period  ...                                               List
0     Short Term  ...  [Frequency of Optimization, Frequency of Data ...
1    Medium Term  ...  [Beta Calibration, frequency of Beta or $ Reba...
2      Long Term  ...                                                NaN
```